# Spring SchedulerFactoryBean throwing SQLException on initialization

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, spring-scheduled

My goal is to instantiate a Quartz Scheduler using a org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean. Whenever I try to do so, a java.sql.SQLException is thrown and my app context can't finish loading. I cannot figure out why Quartz is making a database call. I never configured it to use a JDBCJobStore, I wanted a RAMJobStore.

Here's the Spring xml (legacy app) that instantiates my Quartz Scheduler:

```
    <bean id="quartzJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject" ref="myDataProcessor" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="process" />
        <property name="concurrent" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="quartzTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="quartzJob" />
        <property name="repeatInterval" value="900000" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="quartzTrigger" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0' defined in class path resource [spring/appContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't retrieve trigger: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
 [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.getLifecycleBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:283)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:114)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't retrieve trigger: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
 [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retrieveTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1524)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$12.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:1512)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT.executeInLock(JobStoreCMT.java:245)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeWithoutLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3703)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retrieveTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1509)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.getTrigger(QuartzScheduler.java:1477)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.getTrigger(StdScheduler.java:499)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerAccessor.addTriggerToScheduler(SchedulerAccessor.java:291)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerAccessor.registerJobsAndTriggers(SchedulerAccessor.java:235)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:745)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:216)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:810)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1039)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:850)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1134)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3339)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3384)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.selectTrigger(StdJDBCDelegate.java:1745)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retrieveTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1520)
    ... 53 more
```

Does anyone know why on earth this exception is being thrown?

Thanks!

Comment: You may have forgotten quartz.properties somewhere on your application's classpath and the Spring factory is picking it up. I cannot think of any other reason. I recommend that you search through all your dependencies for "quartz.properties" file.

Answer (score 0):

I never did figure out what I had misconfigured. But this problem was only happening in test code, not main code. [Jan Moravec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3504782/jan-moravec)'s comment was probably the right solution, but I just rewrote my test in such a way that it doesn't use the quartz scheduler.